# Facebook login works in chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth

I have an asp.net website - www.domain.com

I've used the built in OAuth in VS2012 to allow users to register on my site using facebook. Unforutnately, I recently discovered that this has not been working for users on Firefox. What makes this even more strange is that, in the facebook app settings, if I change the site url from http://www.domain.com to http://domain.com, it starts working in firefox and stops working in chrome.

How can I fix this so it will work in both browsers???

Comment: Can you confirm that you can manually reach in your browser both `www.domain.com` and `www.domain.com`? Also in your Facebook App you use specify both.

Comment: Thanks, glautrou, it's working now. The websites were accessible from both browsers, what I needed to do was have both "www.domain.com" and "domain.com" specified in the App Domains field in my Facebook App. The site url field I left as "htt p://www.domain.com". Facebook login is now working in both browsers. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

As stated you have to allow Facebook to use the two domains for your website.

**Solution:**

To do this, go to your Facebook Account: *> Apps > Settings > Basic*.

In this page set both `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` for "App Domains".
That will fix the problem for all browsers and future browser updates.